# What processes do `ps f` show?

Tags: ps

by ps from procps-ng

```
$ ps f | wc -l
225
$ ps -e | wc -l
410
$ ps | wc -l
4
```

`ps -e` shows all the processes and `ps` only those with current terminal as controlling terminal. What processes do `ps f` show? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what system you are using. I would read the manual for your ps command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You original wrote `ps f` but now the question reads `ps --forest`.  The two are not the same...

```
$ ps f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
27614 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -ksh
27656 pts/1    R+     0:00  \_ ps f
 3356 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -ksh
 3370 pts/0    S+     0:06  \_ ssh mercury7

$ ps --forest
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27614 pts/1    00:00:00 ksh
27658 pts/1    00:00:00  \_ ps
```

They contain the same scope as `ps g` and `ps`

eg

```
$ ps g
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3356 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -ksh
 3370 pts/0    S+     0:06 ssh mercury7
27614 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -ksh
28932 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps g

$ ps 
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27614 pts/1    00:00:00 ksh
28755 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Answer (score 4):

The command `ps f`, on an Ubuntu system, would show the exact same processes as `ps` would show, but using an ASCII art process tree.

The option is an option that modifies the output format of `ps`.  It is listed in the `ps` manual on Ubuntu under the section "OUTPUT MODIFIERS".  It therefore does not modify what processes would be displayed.

Using it *together* with another option (e.g. `ps f -e`) would modify only the output format of the command, not the selection of processes.

Comment: Not quite; `ps f` shows more than just `ps`

Comment: @StephenHarris I can't see that they show a different set of processes. I did say that they produce different output formats. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: In my tests, `ps f` showed 4 process, including other terminal sessions, but `ps --format` just showed processes from the current terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), It is not clear `ps f` vs `ps --forest`.

`f`:

> ASCII art process hierarchy (forest).

`--forest`:

> ASCII art process tree.

But both are listed in "**OUTPUT MODIFIERS**" not "OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL".
So they have different outputs.

Then what is the exact difference of `f` vs `--forest`? (Disclaimer: I'm not a professional of UNIX so I haven't read the source code for `ps`)

It is that `--forest` shows one "tree" that has one root (even that is named "forest"), which means a SID (session ID, roughly it is related to the current login session) of the process, so not show any process from a different root. And `f`, on other hand, shows processes that come from different roots, like a forest.

So the use cases of them are:

- Use `ps --forest` when you want to get a "tree" of the processes that started in this session.
- Use `ps f` when you want to get a "forest" of processes that the current user start in any session.